# Why is the edge of the Frame getting cut off? Frame inside a CollectionView with a CornerRadius

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is actually a nested `CollectionView` but I don't think that is part of the issue here- please let me know if it might be and I can include the rest.

Can someone help me understand why the right edge of my `Frame` is being cut off? Including the screenshot and code snippet below:

```
<CollectionView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="5"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding WeeklySchedules}"
                EmptyView="No items currently exist !"                
                x:DataType="formsPages:GroupSchedule">

    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="5"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
                <Frame Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                       CornerRadius="4" 
                       BorderColor="{StaticResource LightTextColor}"
                       HasShadow="False"
                       Margin="0" 
                       BackgroundColor="White"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding DayOfWeek}"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       FontSize="13"
                       Padding="6"
                       x:DataType="formsPages:WeeklyScheduleModel"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding TimeString}"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                       FontSize="13"
                       Padding="6, 6,30,6"
                       x:DataType="formsPages:WeeklyScheduleModel"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

[image]

Comment: your Time label may be laying on top of the right edge of the frame.  Try setting the label's background color to verify

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- I tried that and it didn't work. I was able to fix the issue by putting a right margin on the Frame itself of 2 (feels like a dirty workaround). Still confused as to why the frame border would be cut off on the right side.

Comment: @JordanB I have test the code you provided. The frame border with margin 0 shows the full frame. Please check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/BRv0bQb Maybe i miss something. Could you provide more about it?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are overlapping Label on top of Frame. So some part is invisible

You should use a stacklayout /grid as child of frame to position items.

Alternatively you can set right margin for TimeString Label.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried both of these suggestions and neither worked. I was able to fix the issue by putting a right margin on the Frame itself of 2 (but this feels like a dirty workaround). So it's as if the frame is overstepping the DataTemplate. Still confused as to why the frame border would be cut off on the right side.

Comment: @JordanB, I am still facing the same issue now in Xamarin forms.